# Angular 6 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, rxjs

In my errorhandler I'm trying to navigate to another page when I hit an error.

I try to get a list of items if that fails I want to navigate to "./error401". I've been trying to do it like this:

**UserTablecomponent:**

```
export class UserDataSource extends DataSource<any>{


  constructor(private authservice: AuthService) {
    super();
  }
  connect(): any {
    return this.authservice.GetInstallation();
  }

  disconnect() { }
}
```

this call might be a bit weird. What it does is make a call to the rest see what ID I have based on the token. then uses the ID in the next call

**auth.service**

```
  GetServiceProviderId(): Observable<Info> {
    return this.http.get<Info>(this.rooturl + 'info', { headers: this.reqHeader });
  }

  GetInstallation(): Observable<Installation[]> {
    return this.GetServiceProviderId().pipe(
      flatMap(info => {
        return this.http.get<Installation[]>
          (this.rooturl +
          "installation/?serviceproviderid=" +
          info.ServiceProviderId,
          { headers: this.reqHeader })
      }
    ), catchError(this.myerrorhandle.handleError))
  }
}
```

**myerrorHandle**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class myerrorHandle {

  constructor(public router: Router) { }

  handleError(errorResponse: HttpErrorResponse) {
    switch (errorResponse.status) {
      case 401: {
        this.router.navigate(["./error401"])
        break;
      }
      default: {
        console.log("todo");
        break;
      }
    }
    return throwError('an error was thrown');
  }
}
```

and this is were I want to navigate to "./error401" but get the

> errror ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined

This is full error log:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined
>       at CatchSubscriber.push../src/app/myerrorHandle.ts.myerrorHandle.handleError
>   [as selector] (myerrorHandle.ts:18)
>       at CatchSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/catchError.js.CatchSubscriber.error
>   (catchError.js:33)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error
>   (Subscriber.js:80)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error
>   (Subscriber.js:60)
>       at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error
>   (Subscriber.js:80)
>       at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error
>   (Subscriber.js:60)
>       at FilterSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error
>   (Subscriber.js:80)
>       at FilterSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error
>   (Subscriber.js:60)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/OuterSubscriber.js.OuterSubscriber.notifyError
>   (OuterSubscriber.js:13)
>       at InnerSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/InnerSubscriber.js.InnerSubscriber._error (InnerSubscriber.js:18)

Comment: Change catchError to `catchError((err) => this.myerrorhandle.handleError(err)))` otherwise (without arrow functions) the context of `this` is lost

Answer (score 6, accepted):

as @user184994 said:

> Change catchError to catchError((err) =>
>   this.myerrorhandle.handleError(err))) otherwise (without arrow
>   functions) the context of this is lost

Answer (score 0):

You need to use arrow functions in your code to be able to use the class context `this`

```
catchError(() => this.myerrorhandle.handleError));
```